# Haskell: Print Int from list one by one

Tags: list, haskell

I've got a short question regarding something I want to do in Haskell.
What I basically aim to achieve is to make a list of integers from 1 to a specific value y. Like [1..y], and the print this list with spaces between each number

Let's say i have [1..8]

My desired output is ("_" represents spaces):

```
_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8
```

I have played a little bit with different things but without any luck

This is basically what Iv' got so far

```
printLst :: [Int] -> String
printLst (x:xs) = " " ++ putStr (show x) >> printLst xs
```

I've been searching around the web to find any solution to this, but I have not found anything that helps me do this.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You are mixing `IO ()` with `String`s.

Comment: You may do like `putStrLn . join . map ((' ':) . show)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define a function which converts an `Int` to a `String`, then prepends a space to the result.

```
\x -> ' ' : show x
```

Now map this over your list:

```
>  map (\x -> ' ' : show x) [1..8]
[" 1"," 2"," 3"," 4"," 5"," 6"," 7"," 8"]
```

Now we just need to concatenate all the strings into one:

```
> concat (map (\x -> ' ' : show x) [1..8])
" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

This can be simplied using the `concatMap` function:

```
> concatMap (\x -> ' ':show x) [1..8]
" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

which forms the basis for the `Monad` instance for lists:

```
> [1..8] >>= (\x -> ' ' : show x)
" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

or even more briefly, using function composition

```
> [1..8] >>= (' ' :) . show
" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

Once you have the final string, *now* you can worry about printing it.

```
> putStrLn $ [1..8] >>= (' ' :) . show
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 4):

Well you are confusing things here, first of all:

```
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

And you are returning a `String`, so no need to use that. Also, you have no patter for `[]` and singleton list, you can add them to get a better output like this:

```
printLst :: [Int] -> String
printLst [] = ""
printLst [x] = (show x)
printLst (x:xs) = (show x) ++ " " ++ printLst xs
```

If you want to use `IO ()` function, use it in the main function:

```
main = do
  putStrLn (printLst [1..8])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a list processing problem. For an empty list, we can return the empty string, for a non-empty list, we can first yield a space, followed by the `show` of that item, and then recurse on the rest of that list, like:

```
prefixSpace :: Show a => [a] -> String
prefixSpace [] = ""
prefixSpace (x:xs) = ' ' : show x ++ prefixSpace xs
```

Or as a "fold" pattern:

```
prefixSpace :: Show a => [a] -> String
prefixSpace = foldr (\x -> ((' ' : show x) ++)) ""
```

This will *not* print the string. For that you need [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn), but as the signature indicates, if you `putStrLn some_string`, you work with an `IO ()`.